# How to set the macro results into the excel column? Am new to Macro's and very basic. Please explain it

Tags: excel, vba

'Need to set the value of employee(0), employee(1)......,employee(25) in the A column of excel "Sheet1".

```
Sub testingarray()
For n = 0 To n = 25
employee(n) = Chr(n + 65)
Next n
For n = 0 To n = 25
MsgBox employee(n) 
Next n
End Sub

'Tried to use this:** Please say if am wrong
Public Sub putvalue()
Range("A1").Value = employee(0)
'Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = employee(n)
n = n + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it helps.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723422/moving-data-between-excel-sheets

Answer (score 4):

You can use a similar loop

```
Public Sub putvalue()
dim n as long

For n = 0 To n = 25
employee(n) = Chr(n + 65)
Next n

for n=0 to 25
cells(n+1,1).Value = employee(n)
next n

End Sub
```

You can also do without the array altogether:

```
Public Sub putvalue()
dim n as long

for n=0 to 25
cells(n+1,1).Value = Chr(n + 65)
next n

End Sub
```

Or even faster

```
Public Sub putvalue()
range("A1:A26").formular1c1= "=char(row()+64)"
range("A1:A26").value=range("A1:A26").value

End Sub
```